# 4003: Data item to large sending data from wear os to app

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os

I'm developing a wear os app that needs to send a list of "MyObject" to mobile,

```
data class MyObject(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val locations: List<MyLatLong>,
    ...
)

data class MyLatLong(
    val id: String,
    val lat: Double,
    val long: Double
)
```

When I try to send a myObject with 100 or 200 myLatLong objects there is no problem, but when I have 1000 myLatLong objects, I received a 4003 DATA_ITEM_TO_LARGE exception message

I use DataClient to send the DataMapItem with this function:

```
fun sendMyObjectRequest(myObject: MyObject) {
    val dataClient = Wearable.getDataClient(appContext)
    val request = PutDataMapRequest.create("/my_object_path").apply {
        dataMap.putDataMap("key_my_object", myObject.toDataMap())
    }.asPutDataRequest().setUrgent()
    dataClient.putDataItem(request).addOnFailureListener {
        //Exception received
    }
}

//Extension to map MyObject into DataMapa
fun MyObject.toDataMap(): DataMap = DataMap().apply {
    putString("id", id)
    ....
    putDataMapArrayList("locations", ArrayList(locations.map { it.toDataMap() })
}

fun MyLatLong.toDataMap(): DataMap = DataMap().apply {
   putString("id", id)
   putDouble(...)
   ....
}
```

How can I send this objects from wear to mobile?

Comment: Just send one location per data packet.

Comment: But, if  I do it, the value will be override by the last location?

Comment: ??? Why? Which value? You just send all locations one by one instead of one bunch. Explain your problem please. And with every location you send the same id and name. And preferably a sequence number.

Comment: I have to send around 40.000 locations, so the wereable write into /my_object_path, so, when I send the second location, my question is, the first location will disappear?

Comment: You send them one by one. How the receiver handles them i dont know. But what would be the problem if the reiceiver receives a stream of locations? I see no problem. If you see problems for the receiver then tell them.

Answer (score 0):

The first location disappear because you're overwrite it, you are creating new data item with same path. Try to use *createWithAutoAppendedId* instead of *create* method on PutDataMapRequest. If error persists then convert data item to Asset of bytes from your map object. There is a limit size, see the doc.

```
PutDataMapRequest
            .createWithAutoAppendedId(YOUR_PATH);
```